# Web scraping loop for pages and node in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse

Im want make a scrape of this node. In one page run well but I need the other 342 pages. About pages only change the final number, like 1, 2 , 3 to 342.

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(httr) 

# For page 1
website<-'https://cgspace.cgiar.org/discover? 
rpp=10&etal=0&query=cassava&scope=10568/35697&group_by=none&page=1'
link <-  vector()
#loop through nodes
for (i in 1:10){
  link[i] <-website  %>% 
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath=paste0('//*[@id="aspect_discovery_SimpleSearch_div_search- 
    results"]/div[',i,']/div[2]/div/div[1]/a')) %>%
    html_attr('href')
  
}  
pag <- data.frame(link)
pag$link2 <- paste0('https://cgspace.cgiar.org', pag$link)
pag

# link                                        link2
# 1  /handle/10568/71370 https://cgspace.cgiar.org/handle/10568/71370
# 2  /handle/10568/43831 https://cgspace.cgiar.org/handle/10568/43831
# 3  /handle/10568/56285 https://cgspace.cgiar.org/handle/10568/56285


# For page 2
website<-'https://cgspace.cgiar.org/discover?  
rpp=10&etal=0&query=cassava&scope=10568/35697&group_by=none&page=2'
link <-  vector()
#loop through nodes
for (i in 1:10){
  link[i] <-website  %>% 
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath=paste0('//*[@id="aspect_discovery_SimpleSearch_div_search- 
    results"]/div[',i,']/div[2]/div/div[1]/a')) %>%
    html_attr('href')
  
}  
pag2 <- data.frame(link)
pag2$link2 <- paste0('https://cgspace.cgiar.org', pag2$link)
pag2

# link                                        link2
# 1  /handle/10568/90626 https://cgspace.cgiar.org/handle/10568/90626
# 2  /handle/10568/71796 https://cgspace.cgiar.org/handle/10568/71796
# 3  /handle/10568/68788 https://cgspace.cgiar.org/handle/10568/68788
```

The idea is make this in a single loop and have a data frame.

Update question:
Im add in the second for loop this: but show error

```
    all_pags <- data.frame()
    startTime <- Sys.time()
    for( i in 1:1){
    website<-paste0('https://cgspace.cgiar.org/discover? 
     
    rpp=10&etal=0&query=cassava&scope=10568/35697&group_by=none&page=',i)
      link <-  vector()
      Title <- vector()
      #loop through nodes
      for (i in 1:10){
        link[i] <-website  %>% 
          read_html() %>%
          html_nodes(xpath=paste0('//* 
        [@id="aspect_discovery_SimpleSearch_div_search- 
         results"]/div[',i,']/div[2]/div/div[1]/a')) %>% 
        html_attr('href')
        
        Title[i]<-website %>% 
          read_html() %>% 
          html_nodes(xpath=paste0('//* 
      [@id="resultsTable"]/tbody/tr[',i,']/td/div/div[1]/a/span')) %>% 
          html_text(trim = T)
        
      }  
      pag <- data.frame(link,Title)
      pag$link2 <- paste0('https://cgspace.cgiar.org', pag$link)
      all_pags <- rbind(all_pags, pag, Title)
    }
    
    endTime <- Sys.time()
    print(endTime - startTime)
    all_pags

# Error in Title[i] <- website %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath = #paste0("//*[@id=\"resultsTable\"]/tbody/tr[",  : 
# replacement has length zero
```

Im try to obtaind the names of each document and the link in the same loop

Comment: Hello, Miguel. What did you tried so far? please share an example explaining why it does'nt work

Comment: Hi Ric, this code run well. But I need make a loop for al 342 pages. Because make one by one for each page is very time consume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webscraping with `rvest` and `tidyverse` without loop, and WAY faster I believe.
It took 17 seconds to scrape 5 pages. Change `1:5` to whatever pages you want to scrape.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

get_cg <- function(pages) {
  
  cat("Scraping page", pages, "\n")
  
  page <-
    str_c("https://cgspace.cgiar.org/discover?%20%20rpp=10&etal=0&query=cassava&scope=10568/35697&group_by=none&page=", pages) %>%
    read_html()
  
  
  tibble(
    title = page %>%
      html_elements(".ds-artifact-item") %>%
      html_element(".description-info") %>%
      html_text2(),
    link = page %>%
      html_elements(".ds-artifact-item") %>%
      html_element(".description-info") %>%
      html_attr("href") %>%
      str_c("https://cgspace.cgiar.org", .)
  )
  
}

map_dfr(1:5, get_cg)

# A tibble: 50 x 2
   title                                                                                            link      
   <chr>                                                                                            <chr>     
 1 Industrializacion de la yuca                                                                     https://c~
 2 Cassava: a resilient crop with great potential                                                   https://c~
 3 CIAT's Tony Bellotti talks about the Cassava Mealybug in SE Asia                                 https://c~
 4 Cassava in Asia: a potential new green revolution in the making                                  https://c~
 5 Mealybug threat to cassava                                                                       https://c~
 6 A socio-economic study of cassava and cassava starch production in an Andean village in Colombia https://c~
 7 Manual for the construction and operation of a natural cassava drying plant                      https://c~
 8 Advances on Genome Edition of Cassava at CIAT                                                    https://c~
 9 Diseases affecting cassava                                                                       https://c~
10 Cassava cultivation and starch production in an Andean village                                   https://c~
# ... with 40 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Was the most fast solution. The time for 342 pages was 30.60123 mins. Amaizing your help. Tnks!

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a loop

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(httr) 
all_pags <- data.frame()
for( y in 1:342){
    website<-paste0('https://cgspace.cgiar.org/discover?rpp=10&etal=0&query=cassava&scope=10568/35697&group_by=none&page=',y)
     link <-  vector()
     #loop through nodes
     for (i in 1:10){
       link[i] <-website  %>% 
         read_html() %>%
         html_nodes(xpath=paste0('//*[@id="aspect_discovery_SimpleSearch_div_search-results"]/div[',i,']/div[2]/div/div[1]/a')) %>% html_attr('href')
    
      }  
      pag <- data.frame(link)
      pag$link2 <- paste0('https://cgspace.cgiar.org', pag$link)
      all_pags <- rbind(all_pags, pag)
}
all_pags
```

Comment: +1. I would use a different name for the two loops (`for(i in 1:342)` and `for (i in 1:10)`) for clarity and to avoid errors. It may also be more efficient to accumulate each run of the outer loop in a list, then bind after the loop with `dplyr::bind_rows()` or `data.table::rbindlist()`, though I don't know how significant that difference would be.

Comment: Im currently run for 342 pages. For 10 pages the time was 4  minutes. For all 342 pages the time calculate is 4.5 hr.

Comment: Im add this code for get the name of each link, but dont run well. Update quenstion.